# how to change font family in chemfig

Tags: fonts, chemfig

I am learning to use the `chemfig` package and get the structures to match certain templates. One of the parameters that is important, is the font size and font family of the atoms. So far, to create a typical structure in a figure I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\bondlength}{14.4}
\FPeval{\bondspacing}{clip(\bondlength*0.18)}
\setchemfig{
double bond sep=\bondspacing pt, %space between multiple bonds lines
atom sep=\bondlength pt, %distance between atoms (bond length)
cram width=2 pt, %width of wedged and hashed bonds (bold width)
cram dash width=0.5 pt, %thickness of lines in hashed bonds
cram dash sep =2.5pt, % distance between lines in hashed bonds (hash spacing)
bond offset=1.6 pt, %space between bond and atom (margin width)
compound sep=10 em,%separation between compounds
arrow coeff=1, %default length of the arrow
arrow offset=0.75em, %distance between arrow ends and compounds
arrow label sep=3pt, %distance between arrow and label
scheme debug=false, %show the anchors 
%atom style=red, %color atoms
%bond style=red, %color bonds
bond style={line width=0.6pt}, %bond line width - can be combined with color as bond style={line width=1pt,red}
%compound style={draw,line width=0.5pt,semitransparent,text opacity=1,inner sep=8pt,rounded corners=1mm}, %draws a box around each compound - needs the argument A\arrow([fill=red]--[fill=blue]) to work
}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\normalsize\sffamily\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}
\centering
\scalebox{.8}{
\chemname{\chemfig{-[:108]-[:168]=_[:222]-[:150]=_[:78]-[:6]S(-[:294])}}{\cmpd{ethylcompound}}}
\caption{This is the compound (\cmpd{ethylcompound}).}
\label{scheme:compound}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

(pardon the comments).

But changing the `\sffamily` doesn't seem to change the output font.

The current output is:

[image]

Comment: That looks quite right, doesn't it? The `S` is sans-serif. Note that the `\sffamily` isn't doing anything meaningful, as you use `\mathsf` anyway.

Comment: I was hoping I could swap families to roman, bold, or whatever the required format is (e.g. for different journals).

Comment: Wait, are you changing `\sffamily` but leaving `\mathsf`?

Comment: is this wrong? sorry, I've very new to this all. I'm not even sure why I needed the mathsf in the first place. This code is a mixture of codes I've collected around. I think it has something to do with allowing chemical structures like CO2H (with the 2 subscript) through `\ce{CO2H}`.

Comment: `\mathsf` uses the math sans-serif font. Once you have _that_, everything else you put outside of `\ensuremath` is rather useless (except size commands).

Comment: fair. I changed that bit to `\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\normalsize\sffamily\mdseries{#1}}` and this seems to work fine. Unfortunately, I now have to use the `\ce{NH2}` command every times it's used within a `\chemfig` but it will do.

Comment: Sorry but I still do not exactly understand what you are trying to achieve. `\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}` is everything you need, and does not force you to use `\ce` in the argument. But apart from eliminating `\normalsize\sffamily` (which do nothing in this case) you already had this in your question. So: what is the question?

Comment: I am trying to have a handle with which I can change the font of the atoms (and, if possible, still be able to type NH2 instead of \ce{NH2}, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Since `chemfig` uses math fonts to print letters, you can use the `mathastext` package with the `subdued` option, like so

```
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}
\Mathastext[chem] % create a math version for chemfig
\usepackage{chemfig}
\let\chmf\chemfig % copy the chemfig command
\renewcommand*{\chemfig}[1]{{\MTVersion{chem}\chmf{#1}}} % set the math version before printing
```

This way, the maths in the document remain the same, but your atoms will be printed with your text font.